# Is it appropriate to leave window sills unpainted so they can breathe?

Tags: windows, paint, exterior

I have a contractor who is painting my windows on my house. The windows are pretty old and needed a fair bit of TLC.

After the job was finished, I inspected the job they did. I found that underneath the window sills was unpainted leaving either chipped paint from previous paints, or just exposed wood.

The contractor said that this was intentional as it lets the windows breathe.  Is he giving me the runaround or pulling my leg or is this a real thing?

Sources would be appreciated if you have them!

Thanks!

Comment: Photos? And terminology: the frames that hold glass are called sashes. Is it missing paint on the side or bottom of the sash that you’re talking about?

Comment: Seems kind of obscure. The bottom of the sash or sill would be prime places for bare wood to suck up unwanted water. Discussion here: https://thehistoricdistrict.org/viewtopic.php?t=12471 seems to indicate that it isn't 100% agreed upon while being perhaps a common practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of opinion, but in many years of remodeling older homes with wooden windows in a climate with plenty of rain and show I don't recall ever seeing unpainted sills. That's the exact place I'd *want* paint for weather protection, and the unfinished outside of the window frames should offer plenty of respiration potential.

You decide, then seek some agreement with your painter if you'd like changes.